# Using vuejs with existing html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a list of elements, rendered server-side.

Each item has a button that changes its status.

```
<div class="list">

  <div class="list-item" data-is-published="1" data-item-id="11">
    <div class="item-link">Item 1</div>
    <form method="post" class="list-item-form">
      <div class="vue-mount">
        <input type="submit" name="changeStatus" class="button-unpublish" value="Unpublish">
        <!-- some hidden fields -->
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item" data-is-published="1" data-item-id="12">
    <div class="item-link">Item 2</div>
    <form method="post" class="list-item-form">
      <div class="vue-mount">
        <input type="submit" name="changeStatus" class="button-unpublish" value="Unpublish">
        <!-- some hidden fields -->
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'm using the following code to replace each item with a vue component

```
var ms = document.querySelectorAll('.vue-mount')
for (var i = 0; i < ms.length; i++) {
  new Vue({
    render: h => h(SubscriptionButton)
  }).$mount(ms[i])
}
```

And on the component i get the values of `data-is-published` and `data-item-id` and set them on the component

```
<template>
  <input
  type="submit"
  @click.prevent="changeStatus()"
  :value="isPublished === 1 ? 'Unpublish' : 'Publish'">
</template>

<script>
export default {
....
  created: function () {
    const el = this.$root.$el.parentNode.parentNode
    const status = el.dataset.isPublished
    this.isPublished = parseInt(status)
    this.itemID = el.dataset.itemID
  }
}
```

I'm doing it this way to ensure that it works even if javascript is disabled, but the part `this.$root.$el.parentNode.parentNode` doesn't feel right.

Is the way I'm doing it ok? Are there better ways to achieve the same?

---

**EDIT**

I can put the data attributes on the element that vue will mount to and access them with `this.$root.$el.dataset`.

What I'm not sure about is how compliant to the best practices the use of `this.$root.$el` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Element.closest` (with a polyfill if IE support is required)

```
const el = this.$root.$el.closest("*[data-is-published]");
```

That avoids having to know the hierarchy depth of the DOM.

Info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

**Edited to add:**

The appropriateness of using `this.$root.$el` depends on how you plan to structure the code. If the element you're trying to find is guaranteed to be a parent of the Vue application, then starting the search from `$root` is fine. If that bothers you, though, starting the search from `this.$el` instead would work.

The less conventional part of your approach is that it effectively creates a separate Vue application for each `.vue-mount`

Comment: It's the `this.$root.$el` part that I'm not sure about. Is it good practice to use `this.$root.$el` like this?

Comment: updated answer, but there's nothing particularly wrong with accessing `this.$root.$el`